# Javascript changes all array element 's HTML code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create "div" elements and trying to change their inner HTML with Javascript but it doesn't change the specific element of an array instead it changes all element's HTML code.

```
let bs_length = 2;
const bs_divs = new Array(bs_length).fill(document.createElement("div"));
bs_divs[0].innerHTML = "Hi";
console.log(bs_divs[0].innerHTML); // Hi
console.log(bs_divs[1].innerHTML); // Hi
```

How can I change this code so that it only changes first element's HTML?

Comment: There is only one element being created. Then you fill your array with the same object (element).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) gets passed an object, it will copy the reference and
>   fill the array with references to that object.

Use `Array.from()`

```
Array.from({length:bs_length}, () => document.createElement("div"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array is `bs_length` elements long, but they are all actually the same. Like in many OOP languages, you need to understand the difference between a primitive / immutable value (e.g. `1`, `true`, `"hello"`) and objects (e.g. `[1, 2, 3]`, `{foo: "bar"}`, or DOM elements). The latter are not trivially copied and if you do a `fill` with an element, you fill the array with references to the *one* element. @guest271314's answer provides an one-liner to `fill` with new elements. It is a shortcut to something like:

```
let bs_divs = new Array(bs_length);
for (let i = 0; i < bs_length; i++) {
  bs_divs[i] = document.createElement("div");
}
```